# SQL query, where = value of another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to make a query that simply makes this, this may sound really dumb but i made a lot of research and couldn't understand nothing.

Imagine that i have two tables (table1 and table2) and two columns (table1.column1 and table2.column2).

What i want to make is basically this:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 where table2.column2 = '0'
```

I don't know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is there a relation between these tables? A foreign key?

Comment: @Adam yes, there is a foreign key :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to apply join between two talbes and than you can apply your where clause will do work for you

```
select column1 from table1 
   inner join table2 on table1.column = table2.column
   where table2.columne=0
```

for join info you can see this

Reading this original article on **The Code Project** will help you a lot: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx).

[image]

Find original one at: [Difference between JOIN and OUTER JOIN in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-full-join-in-mys/6188334#6188334).

Comment: @Sajmon, thank you for the tutorial, so basically this is what i want right?
`Select Id from CheckList INNER JOIN CheckRow on CheckList.Id = CheckRow.ListId where CheckRow.Custom='0'`

Comment: Can you do this with 3+ tables?

Comment: This is a very useful diagram. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 
    where t1.id = t2.table1_id and t2.column2 = '0')
```

assuming table1_id in table2 is a foreign key refering to id of table1 which is the primary key

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any kind of natural join between two tables.

You're asking for

```
Select Houses.DoorColour from Houses, Cars where Cars.AreFourWheelDrive = '1'
```

You'd need to think about why you're selecting anything from the first table, there must be a shared piece of information between tables 1 and 2 otherwise a join is pointless and probably dangerous.